# How to solve this set of equation without constructing a Lagrange function?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lagrange-multiplier

I'm trying to optimize $\vec v A \vec v^T$ for its maximum under the constraint $\vec v \vec v^T \ = \ 1$. However, I'm not allowed to turn it into a form of Lagrangian function $L(\lambda,v,A)$.
How can I solve it by expanding these equation? Thanks.

$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
   \nabla (\vec v A \vec v^T) \ = \ \lambda \nabla (\vec v \vec v^T) \\
   \vec v \vec v^T \ = \ 0
  \end{array}\right.
$$
where $v$ is a column vector and $A$ is a symmetric matrix. I want to solve it by expanding, instead of constructing the Lagrange function $L(\lambda,v,A)$.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are deriving the maximum variance of PCA and have trouble finding partial derivatives.
Since $A$ is symmetric matrix, you might apply the conclusion
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{v}}\left(\vec{v}^{T} A \vec{v}\right)=2 A \vec{v}
$$
As for the constraint funtion,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec v} \left( \vec v^\top \vec v \right) = 2 \vec v
$$
Then you can simply put them together
$$
2A\vec v = 2 \lambda \vec v \\
A\vec v = \lambda \vec v
$$